# Replying to a specific person's comment

Tags: support

I checked the FAQs to look for an answer without any luck. Forgive me if it is there and I overlooked it. I recently asked a question with the title: [Causality in a gedanken experiment on the hydrogen atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/causality-in-a-gedanken-experiment-on-the-hydrogen-atom), and John Rennie commented on it. In my response I simply put his name in the *text*. I mean it was like "Yes, John Rennie ..." instead of "@John Rennie Yes ..." I have observed that the latter is pretty standard on this forum and I would like to learn how to do that. Could someone please tell me how that is done?

Thanks.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?][1] on the mother meta.


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: By the way, it's not a forum, it's a Q&A site ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As dmckee wrote in a comment, the full details are at [this question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but I'll reproduce a rule of thumb here: all you have to do is put `@` before the name, and omit the spaces. You don't need to put it at the beginning of the comment. So to reply to John Rennie you could write `Yes @JohnRennie` and so on.

You can also omit characters after the first three. So `@Joh`, `@John`, `@JohnR`, etc. all work equivalently to `@JohnRennie`.

Comment: Comment to the answer(v1): But user John Rennie has a _space_ in-between his first and last name, so it seems that three of your five examples above would not work. Or do they after all?

Comment: Answering my own comment: _They do after all._ See e.g. point 5 in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) meta.SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the comment anyway because I tend to keep an eye on questions where there is an unresolved issue.

If you type @ then start typing the name you should get a little popup suggesting a name. Click on the pop-up and it will fill in the correct name. I'm not sure how these names are created: for me just omit the space so type "@JohnRennie".

BTW did you look at John Baez's article? I see you have a couple of answers, but it doesn't seem to me that either of them really address your question.

Comment: Hi @JohnRennie, thanks for your response. FYI: I don't see the pop-up when I start typing @ + name. You are right. I did not find the post by anna v helpful. It doesn't contain anything I don't already know. Yes, I saw John Baez's article before posted my question. I am familiar with the EPR paradox and its resolution. Baez's argument sort of make sense; it falls into a category descriptions which are able to explain a specific scenario, but extremely difficult to apply to other situations, namely the hydrogen atom example.